# Comparison of a single field to two fields in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a table in Microsoft Access which acts as a static list of countries(named country table), with a country_id field as a primary key identifier. I'm attempting to use country_id within the static list and compare them to another table (named references table) which hold country references (country_ref1 and country_ref2). Please note that the references table have duplicate entries within country_ref1 and country_ref2 and also include nulls/empty values. All fields are of the same type "Short/Text", and consist of two letters when populated.

**If the country_id in the country table DOES NOT match country_ref1 AND country_ref2 in the references table, i'd like the country_id to be populated in my query.**

This is what I've come up with so far, however it's not working (perhaps due to the "NOT IN" statement not accounting for nulls). I've also tried using LEFT JOIN & NOT EXISTS with no solution.

```
SELECT country_id FROM country WHERE country_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT Country_ref1 FROM References) AND country_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT Country_ref2 FROM References)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT c.country_id
FROM country as c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM References r
                  WHERE c.country_id IN (Country_ref1, Country_ref2)
                 );
```

Comment: Looks like it works, although I had to tweak it since i'm searching for missing country_id's from the static table. I instead am selecting country_ref1 and country_ref2 instead of country_id since it would be missing. Thank you!